# Separate table for each year in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-migration

How can implement tables based on year in Laravel, like `Orders2020`, `Orders2019`, `Orders2018` etc. And how to switch between?

Comment: If you have a single table with a `year` column and an appropriate index you can use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) in Laravel . I don't see any compelling use case for multiple tables. Alternatevely you can have a yearly scheduled task that copies `orders` into a new `ordersXXXX` table and clears that table. That way the only  table written to remains the same

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about do it manually and delete old records, wondering if there is a way to do it automatically in laravel, thanks for suggesting scopes

Comment: Wonder why would you want to have so many tables. You can have a single table and have multiple data in it. Just select the data you want from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a model with huge datas, and every month it will generate nearly 10 million+ records, so I split its table horizon too.

The solution is like this below,

#### In your Order model:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = '';
    public function __construct($year='')
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (empty($year)) {
            $tablename = 'orders'.Carbon::now()->year;
        } else {
            $tablename = 'orders'.$year;
        }
        $this->setTable($tablename);
    }
}
```

So you can get the table you want:

```php
$orders2018 = new Order('2018');
$orders2018->where(...)->get();

$orders = Order::where(...)->get(); // will search from the table this year.
```

Comment: That's great way, how you auto generate Table for each year?

Comment: @Mohsen you can use schedule to generate the table before the next year. For example, you can make a  command to generate table-2021 in 2020.

Comment: how do you do count / sum for multiple table? lets said 2018 to 2020

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

example:

```
public function scopeYear($query,$year)
{
    $this->table = 'orders'.year;
    return $query;
}
```

- To get from table of orders2019  just use `Order::year('2019')->get();`
- To create data to table of orders2019  just use `Order::year('2019')->create($data);`

Comment: `'orders'.year ` must replace with `'orders'.$year`

`public function scopeYear($query,$year)
{
    $this->table = 'orders'.$year;
    return $query;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Order::from('orders_2019')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have 3 tables with same schema
i used this structure to handle that

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ReportValues extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;      

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'report_id',
        'item_id',
        'value',
    ];

    public function scopeGenerate($query, $type, $date){
        $table_name = $type."_".$date;
        if (!Schema::hasTable($table_name)){
            Schema::create($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->integer('report_id');
                $table->integer('item_id');
                $table->tinyText('value');     
                
                $table->unique(['report_id', 'item_id', 'user_id']);
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('report_items');                
            });
        }        
        return $query;
    }
    
    public function scopeSalaries($query, $date){
        $this->table = 'salaries_'.$date;
        return $this;
    }

    public function scopeContracts($query, $date){
        $this->table = 'contracts_'.$date;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and then use this command to use them :

generate table for each month clients salary :

`ReportValues::generate('salaries', '202101')`

and then

`ReportValues::salaries('202101')->get()`

or generate contract table for each year
`ReportValues::generate('contracts', '202101')`
and then
`ReportValues::contracts('2021')->get()`

My tables was :

`salaries_202101`
`contracts_2021`